# Sharing remote settings between Windows Phone and Windows 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8

I currently have an app that runs on both Windows 8 and Windows Phone 7. What I would like to do is to be able to access the RoamingSettings that I am using for Windows 8 on my Windows Phone 7 version. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing built in.

You can do it yourself by essentially doing the roaming by yourself - you save the data to a central location and have the user log in (either your own login or live, or Facebook etc).

Comment: Hmmm I suspected as much. Is there any possibility that the last update to windows phone(7.5) will add this functionality. I really love the simplicity and elegance of the RoamingSettings and it is a shame the two Windows products couldn't utilize it.

Comment: Do you mean 7.8? 7.5 has been out for a while. I honestly don't know, but I think that 7.8 will not have any such significant changes. Best bet is 8.0 in that regard (though I don't know if it's gonna be there or not either :))

Comment: Yes, sorry it was late. I did mean 7.8. I supposed I could just leave the Windows Phone 7 crowd on there own island and hope that adoption of the Windows 8 Phone is far more successful.